# FreeBSD pkg repository not updating and thinks it is up to date

Tags: repository, freebsd

I was installing a package using pkg and cancelled during the update check phase. I think this bugged it and now when I run pkg update it says it is on the latest versions. However, it most definitely is not.

Is there a way to force a clean repo list to pull the latest version info?

This is the error when I try to install php56 for example:

```
username@shavedbox:/usr/home/username # pkg install php56
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
The following 1 packages will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
        php56: 5.6.6

The process will require 15 MiB more space.
2 MiB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/latest/All/php56-5.6.6.txz: Not Found
```

(The most recent version is 5.6.7 so the file is obviously not found)

Any help is greatly appreciated! Not too used to FreeBSD...

Answer (score 11):

The answer was simple.

```
pkg update -f
```

And then it worked fine. I need sleep.